# error capturing the transaction

Tags: php, magento, braintree

I'm new to php and magento, I'm using the Braintree sandbox environment and everytime I go through the checkout at the point of submitting order I get a pop-up with this error -

```
There was an error capturing the transaction.
(Transaction declined: Credit card number is required.
CVV is required.)
```

Websites - http://www.coronafactory.com http://www.tvbedfactory.com

Though they were working before it seems to be effecting both sites, I have checked and cannot find any plugins that would conflict with this plugin, I was told by Braintree "it seems that the Braintree.js widget is being initialized, but the resulting object is never being used." "the file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/braintree/review_js.phtml not being included in your checkout form. This file has the javascript responsible for encrypting the form values and giving them the proper name."

I have put in debugging code 'alert('hello');' in the file with no luck, it seems to not be looking at that file at all.

Comment: then the file must not be included. or a cached version is being read.  add some query string to the file path and try again

Comment: @DevZer0 can you suggest a query string to add, and which file should I add it to. Thank you

Comment: the files you included the `alert` that was not showing, `?_=Math.random()`

Comment: @DevZer0 nothing I put at the end of the document  <script>
  function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}
 </script> and its not working, nothing appears but the same error

Comment: I work at Braintree. When our support team find a solution to your problem they'll make sure to post it here as well. We're still trying to track it down for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braintree dev here. In the event anyone else runs across this problem, here's what happened.

A Magento theme had introduced some errors in `checkout.xml` that prevented the form from rendering correctly. This in turn prevented the Braintree encryption javascript from triggering properly.

For any problems with a Braintree integration, don't hesitate to reach out to [Braintree's Support Team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for help.